# configure Servlet holder in Jetty as Spring boot embdeed server

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to move our legacy jetty application to Spring boot application where jetty will be used embedded server .

Is there a way to configure below piece of code in Spring boot ?

```
ServletHolder applicationHolder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
        applicationHolder.setInitParameter(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, packages);
        applicationHolder.setInitOrder(0);

        ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(options);
        contextHandler.setContextPath(contextPath);
        contextHandler.addServlet(applicationHolder, "/*");
```

Comment: How are you registering the `ServletContextHandler` with Jetty at the moment?

Comment: I'm adding `ServletContextHandler` in `Handler` and setting handler as `Server.setHandler(handler[])`